# How to get the difference between (multiple) two different rows?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a set of data containing some fields: `month`, `customer_id`, `row_num` (RANK), and `verified_date`.

The rank field indicates the first (`1`) and second (`2`) purchase of each customer. I would like to know the time difference between first and second purchase for each customer and show only `its first month` = month where `row_num` = 1.

https://i.ibb.co/PjJk5Y0/Capture.png

So my expected result is like below image:

https://i.ibb.co/y5Mww7k/Capture-2.png

I'm using `StandardSQL` in `Google Bigquery`.

````
row_num, verified_date
  from table
  GROUP BY 1, 2```
````

Comment: Please _delete_ the image links, and instead include all of this data directly in your question, as _text_, formatted with four or more spaces on each line.  External links can, and often do, break over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using a pivot query here, aggregating by the `customer_id`:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN month END) AS month,
    customer_id,
    1 AS row_num,
    DATE_DIFF(MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 2 THEN verified_date END),
              MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN verified_date END), DAY) AS difference
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    customer_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, actually I have another question. `MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN month END) AS month` query works very well, it will show us all the months in the query. How if I want to filter it to just want to show month 1/2/3/4 for example? I use `ANY_VALUE(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 AND (month IN (1,2,3,4)) THEN month END) AS month` the outcome is 1, 2, 3, 4 and NULL. Why is there NULL in it?

Comment: You should really ask a new question.